# Surprised error while building apps "Couldn't find outer class" after update to gradle3.1.0-beta1(Android Studio 3.1 Beta1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

run: ./gradlew clean assembleDebug

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Couldn't find outer class xxxxx/SomeClass$someMethod$1$1$2 of xxxx/SomeClass$someMethod$1$1$2$1

execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDevDebug'.
```

[issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72750890)

Same problem https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7u8tug/android_studio_31_beta_1_is_available/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

workaround solved:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72750890#comment10

a bug is also filled at JB.

Answer (score 0):

try adding android.enableD8.desugaring = true in gradle.properties file

then clean and rebuild project